# Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when reading file from S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read some files from S3 and do some processing on each file. I can get through some files, but I keep getting **Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset** at the same line in a particular file during processing. The file in question should be ok though because I can process it locally using the same class and method (conversionUtils.convert()).

Service class:

```
public class FileService {

  @Inject
  private S3Utils s3utils;

  private ConversionUtils conversionUtils = new ConversionUtils();

  public void processFile() {
    List<S3ObjectSummary> files = s3utils.getAllFiles();
    List<S3Object> unprocessedFiles = s3utils.getUnprocessedFiles(files);

    for(S3Object file: unprocessedFiles) {
      InputStream content = file.getObjectContent();
      List<Record> records = conversionUtils.convert(content); //Exception thrown here
    }
  }
}
```

S3Utils class:

```
@Component
public class S3utils {
  @Inject AmazonS3 amazonS3;

  public List<S3ObjectSummary> getAllFiles() {
    ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName('something').withPrefix('some_prefix');
    ListObjectsV2Result result = amazonS3.listObjectsV2(request);;

    return result.getObjectSummaries();
  }

  public List<S3Object> getUnprocessedFiles(List<S3ObjectSummary> files) {
    //do some filtering here

    List<S3Object> unprocessedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary : filteredSummaries) {
      S3Object s3Object = amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(summary.getBucketName(), summary.getKey()));
      unprocessedFiles.add(S3Object);
    }
    return unprocessedFiles;
  }
}
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()).build();
  }
}
```

I've read some other threads with similar errors where the issue was that the AmazonS3 client was being garbage collected, and therefore closing the stream, but I'm wondering if that's the case here. Any ideas on what the issue is? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to overcome this by setting the [`ClientConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#withTcpKeepAlive-boolean-) to keep the connection alive

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder
   .standard()
   .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
   .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withTcpKeepAlive(true)) //Note withTcpKeepAlive method is on ClientConfiguration
   .build();
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue when reading and processing large files off of the S3 bucket. This solution worked for me too.

Comment: I'd like to see the solution when using the v2 client as well, but thanks for getting my on the right track!

Comment: The method withTcpKeepAlive(boolean) is undefined for the type AmazonS3ClientBuilder is what I see

Comment: This answer is from 2019 and probably outdated. I don't work with aws anymore. Feel free to update it with the necessary changes by using the edit functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue with aws sdk **1.X**.

Strange thing here is, it's working fine in local machine and Connection reset while application runs on server.

Tried with `withTcpKeepAlive(true)`, but result was same ie,

> Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

### A workaround

I tried `withRange(startPosition,endPosition)` until I read all data and it  worked.

Answer (score 0):

After i upgrade s3 proxy to 1.6.0 and aws-java-sdk-s3 to 1.1.285 connection reset issue is fixed.